# Web applet game design

Tags: java, web-applications, applet

I making web games in java and having troubles each time when getting to the GUI design, usually I'm looking at others codes and copy most of the design, and I can't decide which design I should use. I used Applet, Canvas, JFrame. What I need is the main loop and draw function that changing between different games. So what class should I use and what design, which is better, why, maybe links to useful tutorials and examples... Please explain your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want some code to dissect, you should check out [Killer Game Programming in Java](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/)

It's a good book, even if it now uses old libraries. I bought it a few years ago. If you don't fancy buying it, you can still download all the source code from the website

You can pretty easily abstract away the choice between using an Applet or Java Web Start. If made to choose, I'd go with JWS, purely because I find it easier to setup a development environment to debug.

These two links demonstrate how to use JFrame v Canvas:

1. **JFrame** http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html
2. **Canvas** http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Canvas

Answer (score 2):

- An Applet (or JApplet) is embedded in the web-page, and thus has only the space given to it by the browser. It stays there as long as the page is shown.
- A proper (J)Frame is its own window, thus can be as big as the windowing system (and screen size) allows - and it can be closed without closing the browser page (and the applet in it).

This is the main difference. You could simply do your drawing in a own Canvas (for AWT) or JPanel (for Swing) and put this inside the (J)Applet or (J)Frame, thus abstracting the difference between both away until you are ready to decide.

Answer (score 1):

I would develop your application using a JFrame that contains JPanels in it.

When you're ready to go to the web, you can use java web start to launch your JFrame.

I used the java tutorials from Sun and they were very effective.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info

Comment: why not applet or canvas? can you show some links.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrapper class that enables your game to operate either as an applet (JApplet) or as a JFrame-based application.

Then I would write all your game-specific code on a JPanel that is added as a child of either the JApplet or the JFrame. You can use a JPanel in exactly the same way that you previously used a Canvas.

Sample code below:

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AppletApp extends JApplet {

    public void init() {
        // do any applet-specific initialisation here
        getContentPane().add(new AppPanel());
    }

    private static final class AppPanel extends JPanel {
        public AppPanel() {
            // do any common initialisation here
            add(new JButton("Hello World!"));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // do any frame-specific initialisation here
        JFrame f=new JFrame("Frame");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        AppPanel appPanel=new AppPanel();

        f.getContentPane().add(appPanel);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Obviously this is just a toy example - normally you'd want to separate your AppPanel out into a separate class file etc.....

Answer (score 0):

Like Paŭlo Ebermann said developing your own canvas or any other component for the display is the best approach (according to my opinion).

Which component you choose also depends on the libraries you choose. If you only develop using Java2D standard Java components are enough. If you switch to LWJGL, JOGL or other libraries they often provide their own components.

Especially JOGL also provides an specific way to implement the game loop because it is driven by an Thread called Animator. If you want to have your design compatible with JOGL you will have to make your game loop compatible with this thread.